# Stuck on writing a simple method with an if statment

Tags: java, if-statement

Hi  basically I need to write a method to calculate the price of Shirts The first 10 Shirts ordered are charged at $20 per Shirt and then any shirt after are charged at $15 per Shirt. Would any one be able to help me work this out this is what I have so far thanks.

```
    public static double calculateCost(int ShirtsOrdered) {
    double cost = 0.0;

    if (ShirtsOrdered <= 10) {
        cost = cost + 20.00 * ((ShirtsOrdered) / 1);


    } else if ((ShirtsOrdered > 10) {
        cost = cost + 15.00 * ((ShirtsOrdered) / 1);



    return cost;
}
```

Comment: `cost = 15.0 * ShirtsOrdered`...?

Comment: dividing it by one doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest solution would be:

```
public static double calculateCost(int ShirtsOrdered) {
    if (ShirtsOrdered > 10){
        return 200.0 + (ShirtsOrdered - 10) * 15.0;
    }
     return ShirtsOrdered * 20.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must count how many shirts after 10

```
public static double calculateCost(int ShirtsOrdered) {
    double cost = 0.0;

    if (ShirtsOrdered <= 10) {
        cost = cost + 20.00 * ((ShirtsOrdered) / 1);


    } else if ((ShirtsOrdered > 10) {
        cost = cost + 20.00 * (10 / 1);//<-- here the cost for 10 first shirt
        cost = cost + 15.00 * ((ShirtsOrdered-10) / 1); //<-- here make the count



    return cost;
}
```